# Пропал звук после обновления драйверов

Tags: аудио, драйвер, ноутбук, asus, динамик

На ноутбуке Asus F3JC при подключении наушников звук продолжал идти  и на динамике и в наушниках, в меню Звук (Windows 7) наушники не отображались. Обновил драйвера для динамиков, звук вообще пропал (и в наушниках и в динамиках). Объясните что сделал не так и как теперь можно это исправить.

Comment: попробуйте переустановить драйвер в диспетчере устройств

Comment: @MidNightElf так и обновлял, после этого два из трех динамиков перестали отображаться, а последний перестал работать

Comment: у меня так же была такая проблема с ноутом. Попробуйте удалить устройство, перезагрузить устройство и установить драйвера

Comment: @MidNightElf откатил драйвера до предыдущей версии, все стало работать

Comment: откатили через диспетчер устройств?

Comment: Да, покопался в гугле и на сайте майкрософт и нашел способ отката